# Are there side effects of using Javascript non-attached iframes?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I use non-attached iframes in some code to send commands to webcams:

```
var frm = document.createElement('iframe');                                                                                                                                                    
frm.style.visibility = 'hidden';                                                                                                                                                               
frm.style.display = 'none';                                                                                                                                                                    
frm.src = "http://192.168.200.66/command=27";
```

Notice, I did not do "document.appendChild(frm)".

This works, the iframes send the commands as the cam expects and I've seen no problems but I can find no documentation or examples of such usage.

Are there side effects or problems to using iframes this way?

Comment: What do you mean sending commands, are they JavaScript commands?  If so this seems like an overly-complicated way to do it.

Comment: The cams take an HTTP request as a command, so "GET /command=27" is what they understand. To send that I set an iframe src="http://192.168.200.66/command=27" and that sends an HTTP GET request to the cam, "GET /command=27"

Comment: The way you've described seems like a pretty good way to do this then.  After the command has been made, are you then destroying the "frm" JavaScript object?  Make sure you clean these kinds of things up or things might get slow very quickly.